# How to change the textview color of item listview when that item is on click?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, textview

I have a ListView and each item have a TextView.

I would like change the item TextView color, for example, when user click in that item.

any ideas, examples or tutorials?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [list of states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

For example, create a file called bg_states.xml in your drawable folder an:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
   android:drawable="@color/blue" ></item>
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@color/blue" ></item>
<item 
    android:drawable="@color/black" /> 
</selector>
```

and define it as a background for your TextView:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/bg_states"
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
v.setBackgroundColor(R.Color.Red);
```

in your `onClick` method